# Confusion over a certain practice in functional react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a React component `RecordsView` in my app like this.

```
const RecordsView = ({data}) => {
  return (
    <SearchBar/>
    <Table
      data={data},
      columns=[
        {id : 'name', header : 'Name', renderAs : (v) => <b>{v}</b>}
      ]
    />
  )
}
```

As you can see the `Table` components accepts a `columns` prop, which tells it which attributes to render from the `data` array and how to render them via `renderAs` function.

You can tell for the above implementation that the `renderAs` function will be recreated in memory for each row of the `Table` moreover it will be recreated for each render of the parent component.

I thought of moving the `columns` prop's value outside the component like this, then just pass it to the `Table` component.

```
const columns = [
  {
    id : 'name',
    header : 'Name', 
    renderAs : (v) => <b>{v}</b>}
]
```

My question has several related sub-questions.

1. Is this a bad practice? I use similar approach for rendering form fields `<Form fields={[...]}/>`
2. Isn't this against pure functional programming?
3. Will the instances of `RecordsView` not be garbage collected upon re-renders of the component because of the global reference to `columns` that is outside the function.

Comment: You have a couple syntax errors, but that aside, no it's not bad practice, no it's not against pure functional programming, and no it doesn't prevent garbage collection.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Sorry about syntax errors. I wrote the code for minimal example in the SO editor. Isn't it against functional programming for a function to access an outside variable? Please elaborate.

Comment: Closures are totally permitted in FP...